# Which comic book cover has had the most homages?

Tags: marvel, comics, dc, cover-art

Often you'll see covers paying homage to or parodying a famous comic cover. For example:

[image]

[image]

or

[image]

[image]

or

[image]

[image]

So, which cover has been...well...covered the most?

Comment: The last one even has a trope on TVTropes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PietaPlagiarism

For some re-stealing, see http://www.cracked.com/photoplasty_763_20-annoying-modern-trends-that-are-older-than-you-think_p3/

Comment: Action #1 has to be in the running.

Comment: There's a famous cover of the Justice League fighting Starro that has been re-imagined numerous times in various JL media (such as a cutaway in Young Justice, the cover of a fictional book about the JL in the New 52, another cutaway on the Justice League cartoon, etc).

Comment: How did Reed Richards get wrapped up in all that rope?? Did that massive creature do it? Did he just trip and land in a big heap of rope??

Comment: @Martijn Even [*Multiple Man* got a Pieta cover.](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-aUROjjYkSGQ/UHyt7FjIvkI/AAAAAAAAHgs/AE56l5xTSsg/s1600/X-Factor+%23100027+(659x1024).jpg)

Comment: It's Action Comics 1 without a doubt.

Comment: @Daft The most logical and realistic explanation is that he was trying to throw it and given his unfamiliarity with his new powers he tangled himself up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doubt anything is parodied as much as Action Comics #1, but Amazing Fantasy #15 (the first appearance of Spider-Man) is pretty iconic, too. [This](https://catestsite1.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/homage-covers-amazing-fantasy-15/) page shows several:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think Fantastic Four #1 probably takes the cake - too many to embed them all but check out [this](http://zak-site.com/Great-American-Novel/ff-tributes.html) website - must be a few hundred!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there's also the famous Wanted poster cover first scene in Uncanny X-men 141. They've used that in almost Every comic brand, Marvel, Dc, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]